# Request a WFS layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, layers, vector, wfs, request

I am new to OpenLayers and GeoServer... can someone please help me to show a WFS layer... here is my code:

```
  const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
      return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoservertest/ows?service=WFS&' +
          'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Geoservertest%3Apoi&' +
          'maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
          'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
  });


  const vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Sample Layer',
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#ffff00'
        })
    }))
})
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [ 
      new ol.layer.Group({
            'title': 'Base maps',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    'title': 'Google Maps Satellite',
                    'type': 'base',
                    visible: true,
                    'opacity': 1.000000,
                    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=pl&&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    'title': 'Google Road without Building',
                    'type': 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    'opacity': 1.000000,
                    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    'title': 'Google Satellite & Roads',
                    'type': 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    'opacity': 1.000000,
                    source: new ol.source.TileImage({ url: 'http://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}' }),
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Water color',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                    layer: 'watercolor'

                    })
                }),
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'OSM',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }), 
            ]
        }),

                    new ol.layer.Group({
                title: 'Layers',
                layers: [vector]}),   
    ],
    overlays: [overlay],
   // target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([-73.985130, 40.705896], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 13,
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 25
    }),

  });
```

Comment: Can you add your map portion e.g `map = new ol.Map(...`? otherwise only layer/source are not enough! Thks

Comment: I edited my code, added the ol.Map portion

Comment: What goes wrong?

Comment: I can't call a wfs layer from geoserver....I'm new to openlayers and geoserver

Comment: do you get an error message? does the server explode? are penguins involved? give us some clues please!

Comment: no errors it shows nothing..maybe I cannot grab the layer from geoserver

Answer (score 2):

Your map is using EPSG 3857 and you are calling your layer with another projection for both the layer and the bbox (EPSG:4326)

You should replace part

```
return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoservertest/ows?service=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Geoservertest%3Apoi&' +
      'maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
      'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
```

with

```
return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoservertest/ows?service=WFS&' +
      'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Geoservertest%3Apoi&' +
      'maxfeatures=50&outputformat=json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
      'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
```

Exactly like for official sample http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html

Comment: so in fact your layer did show up but was very small.

Comment: it shows nothing on my map? anyway thanks for the help